# SAS, Merge sample and original data set

Tags: sas

Need some assistance!!

Table 1

```
Weight | visit | Fat     | Married
 101       1       0         0
 201       0       1         0
 760       0       0         1
```

Table 2

```
Weight | visit |   Fat    | Married
 101       1         0         0
 201       0         1         0
 302       0         1         1
 403       1         1         1 
 560       1         0         0
 760       0         0         1
```

I am trying to achieve the following table in SaS (I know how to do this in SQL).

Table 3

```
Weight | visit |   Fat    | Married  |  Visit1 | Fat1   | Married1
 101       1         0         0         1       0         0
 201       0         1         0         0       1         0
 302       0         1         1
 403       1         1         1 
 560       1         0         0
 760       0         0         1         0       0         1
```

I’ll appreciate any kind of help! Thank You

Comment: Have you tried anything? For SO showing an attempt is highly suggested. A video tutorial on merges is here: https://video.sas.com/detail/videos/sas-analytics-u/video/4572997800001/merging-sas-tables-in-a-data-step?autoStart=true&page=1

Comment: i edited to indicate that you want this in SaS, based on your comment to my (now deleted) answer.

Comment: I am novice SaS user. I tried merging the tables - but always end up merging the common variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to `rename` the variables in the second data set specified in a DATA Step `merge` statement:

```
data want;
  merge
    have1
    have2 (rename = (
      visit = visit1
      fat = fat1
      married = married1
    ))
  ;
  by weight;
run;
```

If you are SQL centric "data set" ≈ "table" and "variable" ≈ "column"